# How to use a procedure to update a new table?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table called `sales` and which tracks all the columns such as `Sale_Id`, etc.. and a new table called `sales_2` table which I'm looking to gather data for the past month only from the `sales` table. I would like to create a procedure that looks up what changed today at the `sales` table and go update the changed/added records into the `sales_2` table. How can I write a query in which I can use the `current_dt - 30 days` structure to fetch the changed records?

Answer (score 0):

you could use the [dateadd function](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html).

```
select dateadd(days ,-30,current_date()) before_30_days,  to_date('2013-05-08') as v1, dateadd(year, 2, to_date('2013-05-08')) as v;
```

The procedure could be something like this.
-- untested need sample table structure

```
create or replace procedure TABLE_UPDATE()
returns varchar(200)
language sql
as
$$
declare
  v_sql varchar2(2000);
begin
  let declare varchar := 'update abc  set col1 = (select cc.col1 from cc where cc.sid1 = abc.sid1 and 
                            and dateadd(days ,-30,cc.date_modified));';
  execute immediate declare;

end;
$$;
```